# How can I implement a local testing database for my Azure Website?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-sql-database

I have a website I'm developing that uses an SQL Azure database.  I want to be able to test my website using a database locally hosted on the debugging machine so that my designer can work on style and content without having to deal with the overhead of firing up the Azure emulator and communicating with an external service as he is often in areas with no-connectivity.

I imagine it would be possible to extract the .sql scripts to create the database and execute them every test run, but this seems tedious.  Similarly I'm not sure what the best way to configure these deployment details would be in order to switch between development, and published configurations.  I'm a new web-developer cutting my teeth on a rather large project.

Using ASP.NET MVC4 and have MSSQL 2012 installed for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your SQL azure database as .bacpac format and then import it into your sql server database. It will create all tables and fill with data. You don't need to do it on every test run, just do it once and you will have proper database for debug needs.

Switching between debug and release (or you can rename it if you want, e.g. Local and Production) configurations and using different web.config (or config transformations) is a good way to work with different settings.

If you want to store your db scripts (db structure or data) in your VCS - you can use Entity Framework migrations (new fancy way) or separate project of "SQL Server database" type (old school but proven way :) ).

Also EF migrations allows you to easily recreate db (with different name) on each run (for unit testing purposes. And then you can use SQL Express file instance (keep in mind that it's only for local work, your designer wont be able to access sql express instances afaik)

Comment: This is quite a useful answer.  I've been trying to avoid EF for a variety of reasons and am actually using dapper for O-R mapping.  I've never been exposed to config transformations so that's something I'll need to look into.  Is there a good way to export creation scripts that are both create and update so they could be executed everytime?

Comment: Okay, you can go SQL Database project way - you will have separated project with sql scripts in it. You can generate full script or db differences from it. Also you can reverse-engineer your db back to the project. When VS generates a script for db-deployment - it puts all checks like "drop object if exists and create new one".

Comment: Keep in mind that it could drop your table before creating new one and you can loose data. There should be checkbox somewhere in settings - don't deploy if data loose can occur. And tbh it's not very handy to storing a lot of data - it uses sql bulk insert for filling your tables after creation. So some pre-populated lists with users\roles or dictionaries is fine, but not a 100k entries tables.